# JAVASCRIPT - for variable "i" is not defined

Tags: javascript

Following my code:

```
var a;
var b = new Array('t1');
for(var i =0; i < b.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='<div onclick="a = i;">a</div>';
}
```

The error is: "i" is not defined. How to solve it?

Comment: Just to make sure: you realise that the `i` and `a` variables that you stick in that innerHTML string are not the variables `i` and `a` but just letters in a string, right? That aside, *when* do you get that error? When it runs, or when you click on the resulting link? (because if you try the latter, it will fairly obviously break when it tries to execute `a=i` in global context. Also: don't do this, use function calls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work...

```
var a;
var b = new Array('t1');
for(var i =0; i < b.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='<div onclick="a = '+i+';">a</div>';
}
```